# Simplifing If Statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I am working on an assignment and I well aware of if statements and switch statements. I have this string of code:

```
if (testLength(document.forms[0].lname) == false) {
    isValid = false;
}

if (testLength(document.forms[0].fname) == false) {
    isValid = false;
}

if (testLength(document.forms[0].address) == false) {
    isValid = false;
}

if (testLength(document.forms[0].summary) == false) {
    isValid = false;
}

if (testPattern(document.forms[0].account, /^ACT\d{6}$/) == false) {
    isValid = false;
}

if (testPattern(document.forms[0].department, /^DEPT\d{3}$/) == false) {
    isValid = false;
}

if (testPattern(document.forms[0].project, /^PROJ\d{5}$/) == false) {
    isValid = false;
}

if (testPattern(document.forms[0].ssn, /^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$|\d{9}$/) == false) {
    isValid == false;
}
```

is there a way to simplify a string of if statements like this if they are all related. I tried to think of different ways you can make a switch, but dont think that was possible. This might be the most elegant solution?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you first have `isValid = true`, you could do it like this:

```
var form = document.forms[0];
var props = ["lname", "fname", "address", "summary"];
var isValid = props.every(prop => testLength(form[prop]))
           && testPattern(form.account, /^ACT\d{6}$/)
           && testPattern(form.department, /^DEPT\d{3}$/)
           && testPattern(form.project, /^PROJ\d{5}$/) 
           && testPattern(form.ssn, /^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$|\d{9}$/);
```

You could also apply the predefined array approach to the patterns, like this:

```
var form = document.forms[0];
var props = ["lname", "fname", "address", "summary"];
var patts = [["account", /^ACT\d{6}$/], ["department", /^DEPT\d{3}$/],
             ["project", /^PROJ\d{5}$/], ["ssn", /^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$|\d{9}$/]];
var isValid = props.every(prop => testLength(form[prop]))
           && patts.every(([prop, regex]) => testPattern(form[prop], regex));
```

The idea is that you initialise the `form`, `props` and `patts` variables only once, not every time you need to perform the validation, although it would not be a problem if you did.

Answer (score 2):

You could take an array and check with boolean as callback.

```
isValid = [
    testLength(document.forms[0].lname),
    testLength(document.forms[0].fname),
    testLength(document.forms[0].address),
    testLength(document.forms[0].summary),
    testPattern(document.forms[0].account, /^ACT\d{6}$/),
    testPattern(document.forms[0].department, /^DEPT\d{3}$/),
    testPattern(document.forms[0].project, /^PROJ\d{5}$/),
    testPattern(document.forms[0].ssn, /^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$|\d{9}$/)
].every(Boolean);
```

A different approach is to use an array of property names and use two arrays for checking.

```
var keys = ['name', 'fname', 'address', 'summary'],
    patterns = [
        ['account', /^ACT\d{6}$/],
        ['department', /^DEPT\d{3}$/],
        ['project', /^PROJ\d{5}$/],
        ['ssn', /^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$|\d{9}$/]
    ],
    isValid = keys.every(k => testLength(document.forms[0][k]))
        && patterns.every((k, p) => testPattern(document.forms[0][k], p));
```

Comment: Now that's stylish JS!

Comment: Nice. Just a pity that it does not allow for short-circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each value is a boolean, you could do a logical `&&` for booleans.

```
var isValid = testLength(document.forms[0].lname) && 
              testLength(document.forms[0].fname &&
              .....
              testPattern(document.forms[0].ssn, /^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$|\d{9}$/);
```

Comment: I thought about this, that would be one really long statement